# How can I merge this array? Php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, for-loop

I've been trying to merge this array for several hours, however I do not get it, I have two arrays, one called 'period' and another 'time'

period

```
"periodo":{"periodo":[["2017-06-22","2017-06-23","2017-06-24"],["2017-06-22","2017-06-23","2017-06-24"]]}
```

tiempo

```
"tiempo":[{"inicio":"2:00 am","fin":"3:00 am"},{"inicio":"3:00 am","fin":"4:00 am"},{"inicio":"4:00 am","fin":"5:00 am"},{"inicio":"5:00 am","fin":"6:00 am"},{"inicio":"6:00 am","fin":"7:00 am"},{"inicio":"2:00 am","fin":"3:00 am"},{"inicio":"3:00 am","fin":"4:00 am"},{"inicio":"4:00 am","fin":"5:00 am"},{"inicio":"5:00 am","fin":"6:00 am"},{"inicio":"6:00 am","fin":"7:00 am"}]
```

this is my code

```
public function testArray(Request $request)
               {
                 if ($request!="" && $request->idUser!="") 
                 {
                  $timeslot= new Timeslot;
                  $idUser=$request->idUser;
                  $fecha1=$request->fecha1;
                  $fecha2=$request->fecha2;
                  $tiempo1=$request->desde;
                  $tiempo2=$request->hasta;

                  $slotD=$request->slotH;
                  $i=0;
                  $k=0;
                  $j=0; 
                  $l=0;
                  $m=0;
                  foreach ($fecha1 as $key => $value) {
                     $date1[$k]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
                   $k++;
                  }
                  foreach ($fecha2 as $key => $value) {
                    $date2[$i]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
                   $i++;
                  }

                  foreach ($tiempo1 as $key => $value) {
                     $value=strtotime($value);

                     $time1[$l]=$value;
                   $l++;
                  }
                   foreach ($tiempo2 as $key => $value) {
                      $value=strtotime($value);
                     $time2[$m]=$value;
                   $m++;
                  }


                  foreach ($slotD as $key => $value) {
                     $value=str_replace("minutos","minutes",$value);
                     $value=str_replace("horas","hours",$value);
                     $value=str_replace("hora","hours",$value);
                     $slot[$j]=$value;
                    $j++;
                  }

                  $array=array("horaInicio"=>$time1,"Horafin"=>$time2);

                  for($l1=0;$l1<count($date1);$l1++)
                  {
                   //$datePeriod["periodo"]=$timeslot->returnDates($date1[$l],$date2[$l]);
                   $datePeriod["periodo"][$l1]=$timeslot->createDateRangeArray($date1[$l1],$date2[$l1]);

                   //echo $datePeriod[$l]->format('Y-m-d');
                     }

                  $n=0;
                  for($i2=0;$i2<count($time1);$i2++)
                  {
                   while ($time1[$i2] < $time2[$i2]) {
                     //echo date('g:i:s', $time) . " - ";
                     $tiempo[$n]["inicio"]=date('g:i a', $time1[$i2]);
                     $time1[$i2] = strtotime('+'.$slot[$i2], $time1[$i2]);
                     //echo date('g:i a', $time) . "<br>";
                     $tiempo[$n]["fin"]=date('g:i a', $time1[$i2]);

                     $n++;
                        }
                  }



                 foreach ($datePeriod as $key => $value)
               { 
                   $id=rand();

                 foreach ($tiempo as $value2) {
                   /*
                   $timeslot= new Timeslot;
                   $timeslot->user_id=$idUser;
                   $timeslot->slot_date=$value[$key];
                   $timeslot->inicio=$value2['inicio'];
                   $timeslot->fin=$value2['fin'];
                   $timeslot->slot_id=$id;
                   $timeslot->slot_status=0;
                   $timeslot->save();*/

                   //$response["fecha"][]=$value["periodo"][$key];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$value2['inicio'];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$value2['fin'];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$id;

                     }

                 }

                 }else{
                   $response["success"]=false;
                 }



                // print_r($tiempo); 
                   //print_r($datePeriod);
                 return array("periodo"=>$dates,"tiempo"=>$tiempo);
               // return $response;
               }
```

this is the code of the function createDateRangeArray()

```
               function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
           {
               // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
               // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

               // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
               // that in the main script

               $aryRange=array();

               $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
               $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

               if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
               {
                   array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
                   while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
                   {
                       $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
                       array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
                   }
               }
               return $aryRange;
           }
```

I want my array to look this way

`"fecha":["2017-06-22","2:00 am","3:00 am",11305,"2017-06-22","3:00 am","4:00 am",11305,"2017-06-22","4:00 am","5:00 am",11305,"2017-06-22","5:00 am","6:00 am",11305,"2017-06-22","6:00 am","7:00 am",11305,"2017-06-23","2:00 am","3:00 am",31662,"2017-06-23","3:00 am","4:00 am",31662,"2017-06-23","4:00 am","5:00 am",31662,"2017-06-23","5:00 am","6:00 am",31662,"2017-06-23","6:00 am","7:00 am",31662,"2017-06-24","2:00 am","3:00 am",23887,"2017-06-24","3:00 am","4:00 am",23887,"2017-06-24","4:00 am","5:00 am",23887,"2017-06-24","5:00 am","6:00 am",23887,"2017-06-24","6:00 am","7:00 am",23887]`

One of the ways in which I thought, is to get the foreach to iterate depending on the number of elements inside the array, however I still can not do it, I had previously tried something like this with an array of this type

array
:
`[["2017-06-22"],{"1":"2017-06-23"},{"2":"2017-06-24"}]`

code

```
                foreach ($dates as $key => $value)
               { 
                 $id=rand();


                 foreach ($tiempo as $value2) {
                  /* $timeslot= new Timeslot;
                   $timeslot->user_id=$idUser;
                   $timeslot->slot_date=$value[$key];
                   $timeslot->inicio=$value2['inicio'];
                   $timeslot->fin=$value2['fin'];
                   $timeslot->slot_id=$id;
                   $timeslot->slot_status=0;
                   $timeslot->save();
                   */
                   $response["fecha"][]=$value[$key];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$value2['inicio'];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$value2['fin'];
                   $response["fecha"][]=$id;

                 }

               }
```

However, I can not find the way to access the internal values of the array, since each one will be different, how could I solve this?

Comment: Those are not arrays - they're JSON strings. Parse them into arrays, then merge them. Once merge output as JSON again with `json_encode()`.

Comment: Hi jay, I tried to do it using the function array_merge however the order is the only thing in which it fails